# replacing "." with a character in R

Tags: r, string, replace, letter-spacing

I have a string that is

NAME = "Brad.Pitt"

I want to replace "." with a space (" "). I tried using sub, gsub, str_replace, str_replace all. They aren't working fine. Is there anything that I am missing out ?

Comment: `.` is a special character in regex try adding `fixed = TRUE` or espacing it with either `\\.` or `[.]`.

Comment: If you indent the code line by 4 spaces SO will format it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
NAME = "Brad.Pitt"

gsub("\\.", " ", NAME)
```

Answer (score 2):

The main thing missing is that all the commands you mention regard the pattern as a regular expression, not a fixed string and, in particular, in a regular expression dot matches any character -- not just dot.  You can find out more about these by reading `?"regular expression"`

Here are some alternatives. (1) The first one uses `fixed=TRUE` so that the special characters in the first argument are not interpreted as regular expression characters. We used `sub` which substitutes one occurrence but if there were multiple occurrences and you wanted to replace them all with space then use `gsub` in place of `sub`.  (2) The second escapes the dot with square brackets so it is not interpreted as a regular expression character.  Another way of escaping dot is to preface it with a backslash so using R 4.0 r"{...}" notation we can use `r"{\.}"` as the pattern or without that notation see the other answer. (3) `chartr` does not use regular expressions at all.  It will replace every dot with space. (4) `substr<-` replaces the 5th character with space. (5) `scan` read in the words separately creating a character vector with two components and then `paste` pastes them back together with a space between them.  If there were multiple dots then it would replace each with a space.

```
# 1
sub(".", " ", NAME, fixed = TRUE)
## [1] "Brad Pitt"

# 2
sub("[.]", " ", NAME)
## [1] "Brad Pitt"

# 3
chartr(".", " ", NAME)
## [1] "Brad Pitt"

# 4
`substr<-`(NAME, 5, 5, ' ')
## [1] "Brad Pitt"

# 5
paste(scan(text = NAME, what = "", sep = ".", quiet = TRUE), collapse = " ")
## [1] "Brad Pitt"
```

### Headings

Also note that if the reason you have the dot is that you read it in as a heading then you can use `check.names = FALSE` to avoid that.  Compare the headings in the output of the two `read.csv` commands below.

```
Lines <- "BRAD PITT
1
2"

read.csv(text = Lines)
##   BRAD.PITT
## 1         1
## 2         2

read.csv(text = Lines, check.names = FALSE)
##   BRAD PITT
## 1         1
## 2         2
```